# How can I use $get method without user click (.click) in an app.js file? (jQuery Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have found that this works:

```
$("#location").click(function(){
    $.get("https://freegeoip.app/json/", function(data){
        document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = (data.city);
    });
});
```

I'd like to show the data I gained on the page automatically when the page loads without a user action.
I've tried this, but does not work:

```
$.get("https://freegeoip.app/json/", function(data){
    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = (data.city);
});
```

The error message is:

jQuery.Deferred exception: $.get is not a function ...

When I add the latter script to the html file's head it works again.

So my question is:
How can I use $get in a separate app.js file without a user click?

Comment: Sounds like you might be loading multiple versions of jQuery.js in page and one of them is a *"slim"* version that does not include the $.ajax api

Comment: Great! The "slim" version caused the problem. I changed it to the full version and everything works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK but also no need to load 2 versions either. Should be able to remove one completely